# Could not execute method of the activity. Why the error?

Tags: java, android

I am a novice programmer. Write the program and came across error. Searching the internet, but not found. What could be the problem? Help me please.
Here's the code.

```
public void onAddExpenseClick(View viev){
    final String[] mChoose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mChoose);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HistoryActivity.this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mChoose);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.expense_dialog);
    dialog.show();

    spinner.setPrompt("Title");
    spinner.setSelection(2);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  }
});
}
```

Here's the Log

```
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  ... 11 more
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 02:33:37.512: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at com.droidbrew.travelcheap.HistoryActivity.onAddExpenseClick(HistoryActivity.java:150)
```

Comment: what line is this `HistoryActivity.java:150` ?

Comment: What was the code at line 150?

Comment: 150: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Your adapter is Null. Thats is why there is a NullPointerException

Comment: where do you have the spinner? In activity or dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You have `R.id.spinner` in Your layout.

`findViewById(R.id.spinner)` must be returning null because it couldn't find it and You get NPE when trying to setAdapter in next step.

We can be sure it is not `adapter` variable that is null because You would get NPE in line 149 then.